# Illegal HTML character: decimal 141

Tags: xml, utf-8, xslt-2.0, saxon

We are processing a UTF-8 XML input file with Saxon PE 9.5.1.8 on Mac OS X 10.11. Here is the transform:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="html" version="5.0" encoding="utf-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a">
        <p><xsl:sequence select="text()"/></p>  
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is a hexdump of our XML input file:

```
$ hexdump -C utf.xml
00000000  3c 3f 78 6d 6c 20 76 65  72 73 69 6f 6e 3d 22 31  |<?xml version="1|
00000010  2e 30 22 20 65 6e 63 6f  64 69 6e 67 3d 22 55 54  |.0" encoding="UT|
00000020  46 2d 38 22 3f 3e 0a 3c  72 6f 6f 74 3e 0a 3c 61  |F-8"?>.<root>.<a|
00000030  3e 30 78 43 32 42 35 3d  22 3c 21 5b 43 44 41 54  |>0xC2B5="<![CDAT|
00000040  41 5b c2 b5 5d 5d 3e 22  3c 2f 61 3e 0a 3c 61 3e  |A[..]]>"</a>.<a>|
00000050  30 78 43 32 38 44 3d 22  3c 21 5b 43 44 41 54 41  |0xC28D="<![CDATA|
00000060  5b c2 8d 5d 5d 3e 22 3c  2f 61 3e 0a 3c 2f 72 6f  |[..]]>"</a>.</ro|
00000070  6f 74 3e 0a                                       |ot>.|
00000074
```

The important characters are (i) line 00000040, 0xC2B5 represented as the two `.` characters in `[..]`, and (ii) line 00000060, 0xC28D represented as the two `.` characters in `[..]`.

Here is how to generate our XML input file from a *nix command shell:

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
echo '<root>'
echo -e '<a>0xC2B5="<![CDATA[\xc2\xb5]]>"</a>'    # micro sign
echo -e '<a>0xC28D="<![CDATA[\xc2\x8d]]>"</a>'    # control character
echo '</root>'
```

Our transform terminates with:

```
SERE0014: Illegal HTML character: decimal 141"
```

Decimal 141 is 0x8D, which is the second byte of our control character 0xC28D. Why is Saxon is picking off the 0x8D character and regarding it as invalid? We expected Saxon to regard it as byte #2 of the valid 2-byte UTF-8 character 0xC28D.

We know that when we can create HTML with `method="xml"`; however, doing it that way (i) does not emit HTML5, which we are committed to producing, and (ii) drops the 0xC2 byte from the HTML output.

Comment: Can you show us the XML you feed to the XSLT in addition to the shell code producing it? I am afraid I don't know what `echo` and `echo -e` does exactly. And which output do you want to create? Would it validate as HTML5?

Comment: I looked at a man page for echo and I couldn't find any clues as to what it does about character and byte encoding. Try using the same echo commands to create a file and then do a hex dump of the file to see what bytes it actually contains. I would be pretty confident that you are not creating the XML file you think you are creating, and that the problem occurs long before Saxon gets anywhere near the data.

Comment: I have edited the question to include a hexdump of the XML input file. You can see the two 2-byte characters—the 0xC2B5 micro sign, and the 0xC28D control character—in the output.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, yes, I want the output to validate as HTML5.

Comment: http://ss64.com/bash/echo.html is one place that describes the bash echo command. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html is another

Comment: @MartinHonnen, further to answering your question, the HTML5 output we desire would give some indication of what's in the input XML file. We will probably use [an xsl:character-map entity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156550/how-to-handle-the-illegal-html-characters-in-xsl/23156960#23156960) to transliterate chars like 0xC28D into something readable.

Comment: I tried your stylesheet code with Saxon 9.5, 9.6 and 9.7 against the sample `<root><a>0xC2B5="&#xC2B5;"</a><a>0xC28D="&#xC28D;"</a></root>` and it does create a HTML result document without giving any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, then you want to feed the Unicode character `UC28D` inside an UTF-8 encoded XML document to XSLT. As far as https://dotnetfiddle.net/HuNLpC tells me, the three byte sequence representing that character in UTF-8 is `EC 8A 8D` and not the two byte sequence `C2 8D` your hex dump contains. So I think the problem is with your input or input generation, it does not contain respectively create the right UTF-8 encoding of your character.

See also my comment, if you use XML character references with e.g. `<root><a>0xC2B5="&#xC2B5;"</a><a>0xC28D="&#xC28D;"</a></root>` then Saxon (tested with 9.5, 9.6 and 9.7) does transform the input with your stylesheet to an HTML document without complaining about any errors or illegal HTML characters.